# When would one use mmap MAP_FIXED?

Tags: c, mmap

I've been looking at the different flags for the mmap function, namely MAP_FIXED, MAP_SHARED, MAP_PRIVATE. Can someone explain to me the purpose of MAP_FIXED? There's no guarantee that the address space will be used in the first place.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`MAP_FIXED` is `dup2` for memory mappings, and it's useful in exactly the same situations where `dup2` is useful for file descriptors: when you want to perform a *replace* operation that atomically reassigns a resource identifier (memory range in the case of `MAP_FIXED`, or fd in the case of `dup2`) to refer to a new resource without the possibility of races where it might get reassigned to something else if you first released the old resource then attempted to regain it for the new resource.

As an example, take loading a shared library (by the dynamic loader). It consists of at least three types of mappings: read+exec-only mapping of the program code and read-only data from the executable file, read-write mapping of the initialized data (also from the executable file, but typically with a different relative offset), and read-write zero-initialized anonymous memory (for `.bss`). Creating these as separate mappings would not work because they must be at fixed *relative addresses* relative to one another. So instead you first make a dummy mapping of the total length needed (the type of this mapping doesn't matter) without `MAP_FIXED` just to reserve a sufficient range of contiguous addresses at a kernel-assigned location, then you use `MAP_FIXED` to map over top of parts of this range as needed with the three or more mappings you need to create.

Further, note that use of `MAP_FIXED` with a hard-coded address or a random address is **always a bug**. The only correct way to use `MAP_FIXED` is to replace an existing mapping whose address was assigned by a previous successful call to `mmap` without `MAP_FIXED`, or in some other way where you feel it's safe to replace whole pages. This aspect too is completely analogous to `dup2`; it's always a bug to use `dup2` when the caller doesn't already have an open file on the target fd with the intent to replace it.

Comment: "then you use MAP_FIXED to map over top of parts of this range as needed with the three or more mappings you need to create" Can the original dummy mapping be freed immediately after a second mapping using ```MAP_FIXED``` is done?

Comment: @user3882729: Any parts of it that weren't used can be unmapped, but the parts that were used were already "freed" by mapping over them. If you attempted to unmap again you would not be unmapping the initial dummy map but the actual mappings you wanted to put there.

Answer (score 2):

If the file you are loading contains pointers, you will need to load it at a fixed location in order to ensure that the pointers are correct.  In some cases, this can merely be an optimization.

- Executables which are not position-independent must be loaded at fixed addresses.
- Shared memory may contain pointers.
- Executables which use prebinding will attempt to load dynamic libraries at predetermined memory locations as an optimization, but will fall back to normal loading techniques if a different location is used (or if the library has changed).

So `MAP_FIXED` is not typical usage.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question of when to use it at all.

Comment: @R..: You're right.  I had completely forgotten about remapping.

Comment: Another use case (but not really "the purpose" of this flag) would be to make some data (such as a large, expensive-to-compute graph) position-dependent and also be able to save it to a file to speed up later runs. I'm pretty sure this is frowned upon, but I've been able to do cool things with MMAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE and a malloc wrapper.