# Does mmap addr need to page aligned when using MAP_FIXED

Tags: linux, mmap

The accepted answer to [When would one use mmap map_fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575893/when-would-one-use-mmap-map-fixed) states:
"So instead you first make a dummy mapping of the total length needed (the type of this mapping doesn't matter) without MAP_FIXED just to reserve a sufficient range of contiguous addresses at a kernel-assigned location, then you use MAP_FIXED to map over top of parts of this range as needed with the three or more mappings you need to create."

My question is: do the subsequent mmap calls with MAP_FIXED meant to overlay the reserved page-aligned range, need to pass a page-aligned address argument to mmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [mmap man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) has the info you need (emphasis mine):

> MAP_FIXED
>
> Don't interpret addr as a hint: place the mapping at exactly that address. **addr must be suitably aligned**: for most architectures a multiple of the page size is sufficient; however, some architectures may impose additional restrictions.