# mmap to fix address fails

Tags: c, linux, mmap

I want to map a file stored in ramdisk to a fixed address, but mmap fails.
What mistake I am doing? Is there any other method to do this?

```
int fd =  open("/mnt/tmpfs/hello.txt",
                            (O_RDONLY),
                            (S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO) );
if ( fd < 0 )
     perror("open() error");

struct stat buf;
fstat(fd, &buf);
void * address = aligned_alloc(PGSIZE, buf.st_size)
void *new_address = mmap(address,
                      buf.st_size,
                      PROT_READ,
                      (MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED),
                      fd,
                      0);
if (new_address != address) {
    perror("mmap failed!")
}
```

Comment: What is the value of errno?

Comment: Related: [When would one use mmap MAP_FIXED?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28576674/68587) "Further, note that use of `MAP_FIXED` with a hard-coded address or a random address is **always a bug**. The only correct way to use `MAP_FIXED` is to replace an existing mapping whose address was assigned by a previous successful call to `mmap` without `MAP_FIXED`, or in some other way where you feel it's safe to replace whole pages."

Comment: most likely, the problem is that `buf.st_size` is not a multiple of the page size.