# Allocate region of virtual address space upfront

Tags: c, linux, mmap, virtual-memory

I have several files that I want to map into a virtual address space **consecutively** with `mmap()`. Each file length is a multiple of the page size.

For the first file, I call `mmap()` with the `addr` parameter set to `nullptr`. On the next call, I set the `addr` parameter to the address after the end of the region that the first file was mapped to.

In some cases, I am unable to map all files because `mmap()` ignores the `addr` hint. Is there a way I can pre-allocate the entire region up front and then map the files into the region one at a time?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28576674/453616) (which is about the `MAP_FIXED` flag for `mmap`) provide some hints?

Comment: @gspr Yes, thank you! It sounds like I should `mmap()` an anonymous region upfront, with the region sized to the sum of the file sizes. Then, within that region, I can `mmap()` the files one at a time using `MAP_FIXED`. `mmap()`'ing the anonymous region upfront is important because otherwise you may inadvertently overwrite existing mappings.

Comment: Yep, that's my reading of it too.

Comment: @gspr Thanks for your help! Please feel free to leave an answer and I will accept it, or I'm happy to as well once I code this up.

Comment: The reputation isn't important to me anymore, and I think it's more helpful for others if you answer your own question with the actual code when it works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to thank @gspr for their help with this question!

To ensure you can `mmap()` all of the files consecutively, you must do the following:

1. `mmap()` an anonymous region with a size equal to the sum of the file sizes.

```
void* ret = mmap(/*addr=*/nullptr, file_size_sum, PROT_NONE,
                 MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, /*fd=*/-1, /*offset=*/0);
assert(ret != MAP_FAILED);
```

2. `mmap()` each file one at a time within the pre-allocated region. Importantly, use the `MAP_FIXED` flag.

```
void* addr = mmap(/*addr=*/ret, file_size, PROT_READ,
                  MAP_SHARED | MAP_FIXED, fd, /*offset=*/0);
assert(addr != MAP_FAILED);
```

`MAP_FIXED` instructs `mmap()` to use the exact address specified in the `addr` parameter. If a mapping already exists for `addr`, the mapping is overwritten. Thus, it is important that we pre-allocate the entire region upfront in step (1) so that we do not inadvertently overwrite an existing mapping for something else in step (2) when we use `MAP_FIXED`.