# Python: How to mmap multiple files into a single (address) space? Or equivalently, how to map with a negative offset?

Tags: python, mmap

I ask ideally in python, but even in C/++ if there is no solution in Python. The question is, how can I map 3 files, a.bin, b.bin, and c.bin, each at a different offset into the same memory map (each starting at a different address, without overlaps) in python? Is it possible?

Equivalently, is it possible to map a file to memory using a negative offset, meaning that instead of address 0 in mmap pointing to some arbitrary positive address in the file, I need the other way around, such that an arbitrary positive address in mmap points to the beginning of the file (address 0), which would imply accessing address 0 in mmap would correspond to a location before the start of the file, hence the term "negative", which ideally would be handled as an exception or return some filler value, such as 0xFF.

Comment: This is usually OS-specific. What operating system are you targetting?

Comment: linux (kubuntu 23.10)

Comment: Are the target start addresses page-aligned?

Comment: What problem is this supposed to solve? The actual addresses of the memory map aren't usually of any importance, only that you *can* access the file contents via things like pointers.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: yes, 4KB boundaries (same as pagesize and disk block size)

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Just call `mmap()` 3 times. It will pick non-overlapping regions of memory for each mapping.

Comment: I found a solution: ask chat-gpt. It gives a direct answer, rather than asking why you want to know.

Comment: I thought I had time to write up an answer, but I don't. [You should be able to adapt this answer, though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28576674/5223757) (see the NOTES section of `mmap`'s `man` page for anything not covered there; and consider using the `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE` flag instead).  It's a bit of effort to do with `ctypes`, because the constant values for the flags aren't available from `libc = ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6')`, so you'll have to look them up in the header file yourself.

Comment: @moFEAR Don't trust ChatGPT on this; it's a _subtle_ problem, and ChatGPT tends to output buggy solutions for those.

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is what you mean by "each into the same memory map". Can you post some more details about what effect you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Barmar I understood it fine; see the answer I linked for more details. There's a whole section of the `mmap` man page explaining this exact use-case.

Comment: @wizzwizz: you don't even know what it answered, nor provided an answer of your own. you only asked several questions.

Comment: @barmar: it means that from the same mmap object in python, be able to access data from any of the files, depending on which address range I use as a slice

Comment: @moFEAR See the comment _just above_ that. Another subtlety that I would've included in an answer: you'll have to make a `bytearray` object, not a `mmap.mmap` object, because `mmap.mmap.close()` / its destructor won't do the correct cleanup, and `mmap.resize` would just corrupt the whole thing.

Comment: An `mmap` object can only be associated with one file. If you need to map multiple files, you have to create a separate objects for each.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 My comment wasn't addressed to you. I didn't understand the OP's question.

Comment: I guess what you need to do is define a `MultiMmap` class that allows you to combine multiple `mmap` objects. Its addressing method could then figure out which nested object an address corresponds to.

Comment: @Barmar That is a far better solution, if that's what the OP wants. (Turns out [I didn't understand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusion_of_transparency) the OP's question either; I apologise.)